# Android Listview format text

Tags: android

is it possible to format an item text in the Listview so it would look for example like this:

**part of string is bold** and part is not

Thanks

Comment: are you using standard adapters or a custom list view adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, you'd just have to have two different textviews, one for the bold text, and one for the unbolded text. So you'd have a layout for each row that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/bold_field"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:textStyle="bold"
   />
   <TextView android:id="@+id/non_bold_field"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you'd use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) to map the appropriate pieces of the string to each TextView. If you want the string to appear seamless, you'll probably have to mess around with the [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3agravity) of the TextViews.

Comment: but... I should give it a try maybe. I liked ListView but this seems as the only way

Comment: It's not that bad when you think about it. :)

Comment: ok, I don't want to waste time trying it and then discover that I can't use it because of "something" ;) So just to be sure, It creates something with a layout similar to HTML table? <table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></table>. Every TextView is like <td> in every <tr>? Hope it's not so mad-complicated :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to format your strings..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="part_bold"><b>%1$s</b> %2$s</string>
</resources>

Resources res = getResources();
String part_bold_text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.part_bold), bold_string, normal_string);
```

the string in the xml has 2 arguments, one is bold , the other is normal. use this to get a string(`part_bold_text`) of part bold and a part normal.

HTH.

Comment: Doesn't this assume the strings a static and in an xml resources file though?

Comment: This doesn't work. The formatting is Normal when I put this string into Listview