# Android Listview - html formating of rows

Tags: android, android-listview

is it possible to format text in rows in Listview using html? I need to use `font`, `b`, `i` tags

I use this code to fill ListView

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this,R.layout.resultlist,v));
```

where `v` is a vector array filled with strings

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can use the xml attributes to format the text in a TextView. For example, you can use the [android:textStyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textStyle) attribute to make the text bold, or italic. So if you want bold, you can do `android:textStyle="bold"` or if you want both bold and italic you can do `android:textStyle="bold|italic"`. If you want different parts of your string formatted differently, checkout this [SO Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7999827/527288)

Comment: No, you can. Just do `android:textStyle="bold|italics"` It mentions that in the documentation.

Comment: ah ok. I meant part of string is italic and part is bold

Comment: Edited my answer to address this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use:

```
Html.fromHtml("text with html");
```

But, I think it will slow down your ListView. Try to use android styling in your R.layout.resultlist xml layout. I'm sure you can find a way to avoid html formatting.

Comment: I can't add Spanned var to Vector